# How do I secure a flask api?

Tags: api, flask, flask-restful

My goal is to secure an api through token based authentication on aws beanstalk. Im using flask as a framework. To use the API, the user should only need the url and a token.

I really want to keep it as simple as possible but also secure.

My approach:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    headers = request.headers
    auth = headers.get("auth")
    if auth == lookupTokenInDatabase():
        return jsonify({"message": "OK: Authorized"}), 200

    else:
        return jsonify({"message": "ERROR: Unauthorized"}), 401


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The client request would look like this:

```
import requests

url = "test"

payload = {}
headers = {'auth':'token'}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response)
```

I am aware that this is probably not state of the art, but does it provide at least some type of security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id use something like Flask-JWT-extended , you can generate "api tokens" that would be valid for x/y amount of time once user logs in use flask to send jwt token and save it inside of cookie. After that set up your front end to send the "bearer token" on each request so you could validate the user on back-end.

Comment: What I don't understand is with Flask-JWT-extended the user has to login in order to recieve a key. I only want to use the key to authenticate, that means the key has to be created when the customer is created and not when the customer tries to use the api

Comment: API Keys are not used for user authentication if that is what you are trying to achieve. In general you can create a method that would create a random hashed string and store it in user model when someone create an account, beware of api key collisions and similar things. You can go for hashlib in order to create hashed keys , after that create a wrapper that checks the validation of api key on the views where you need API Key authentication.